# Load StripeCheckout in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use [StripeCheckout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) in my controller. After the script loads `StripeCheckout` is attached to the `window` object, so I created a provider which supposed tor return that object:

```
angular.module('organization.settings').controller('OrganizationSettingsCtrl', [ '$scope', 'StripeCheckout', 'organization',
    function($scope, StripeCheckout, data) {
 ...
}]).provider('StripeCheckout', function ProvideStripeCheckout() {
  var provider = {};

  provider.$get = function( $window ) {
    return $window.StripeCheckout;
  };

  return provider;
});
```

The above code works fine without minification, but once the code is minified I'm getting the following exception:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- StripeCheckout <- StripeCheckout
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20StripeCheckout%20%3C-%20StripeCheckout
at https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:3:20639
at https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6662
at Object.d [as get] (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:5832)
at https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6759
at d (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:5832)
at Object.e [as invoke] (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6169)
at https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6779
at d (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:5832)
at e (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6169)
at Object.f [as instantiate] (https://localhost:3000/app.min.js:4:6294) <div ng-view="" class="container ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Checkout Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout):

> Note: Checkout must be loaded from https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js. Using a local copy of Checkout is unsupported, and may result in user-visible errors.

Therefore, when I placed `<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>` to my index page, it was removed after minification.

The solution was to dynamically append the script to the page body from a controller:

```
angular.module('organization.settings').config(['$routeProvider', 'securityAuthorizationProvider', function($routeProvider, securityAuthorizationProvider){

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.onload = function () {
  console.log("StripeCheckout loaded");
};
```

and creating a factory to retrieve the StripeCheckout object later:

```
angular.module('organization.settings').controller('OrganizationSettingsCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Upload', 'utility', 'StripeCheckout', function($scope, Upload, utility, StripeCheckout) {

  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  ...
  });
...
}]).factory('StripeCheckout', ['$window', function ($window) {
  return $window.StripeCheckout;
}]);
```